# How to redirect a second html page after update the dynamic label in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After click on button in first.html, i have been called a function and updated labels in second.html, but i able to see a second.html not able to see the updated value in labels in second.html.Please help me how to achieve.

```
function updateLabels(){
         $('#entryNumber').text("123");
         $('#responsedate').text("23-9-2015");
         window.location = 'second.html';
}
```

ex:second.html

```
<body>
     <label>Entry Number:</label>
     <label id="entryNumber" for="entryNumber"></label><br><br>
     <label>Respond Date:</label>
     <label id="responsedate" for="responsedate"></label><br><br>
     <label>Response Text:</label> 
</body>
```

Comment: Write that js code in **second.html**

Comment: @Rayon Thanks , but i need to handle through the java script only. because after getting json response i am doing this logic. please tell how to do in js

Comment: JavaScript need to be there in your page, either inline or external to manipulate **DOM**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal in client side via.. 3 options

### 1. By Local Storage

- On first page set your second page label value in local storage.

  ```
      // In 1st page
      function updateLabels(){
      localStorage.setItem('Second_Page_LabelVal', "apple");
         window.location = 'second.html';
      }
  ```
- On second Page get this value from local storage and set it to your labels value

  ```
  // In 2ndPage
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  // Retrieve the object from storage
       var retrievedVal = localStorage.getItem('Second_Page_LabelVal');
       $("2ndpagelabelId").text(retrievedVal);
  });
  ```

### 2. By cookie

- On first page set your second page label value in COOKIES.

  ```
        function createCookie(name,value,days) {
         if (days) {
         var date = new Date();
         date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
         var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
         }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }


          // In 1st page
          function updateLabels(){
          createCookie(('Second_Page_LabelVal', "apple",1);
             window.location = 'second.html';
           }
  ```
- On second Page get this value FROM COOKIE and set it to your labels value

  ```
  // In 2ndPage
  function readCookie(name) {
     var nameEQ = name + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
     var c = ca[i];
     while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return  
               c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
  ```

  }

  ```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  // Retrieve the object from cookie
       var retrievedVal = readCookie('Second_Page_LabelVal');
       $("2ndpagelabelId").text(retrievedVal);
  });
  ```

### 3. By querystring Url

- Redirect page with second page value in query string

  ```
   // In 1st page
      function updateLabels(){

         window.location = 'second.html?SecondpageValue=value1';
      }
  ```
- Get the value from url and set it to label.

  ```
   function getParameterByName(name) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
      results = regex.exec(location.search);

        return results === null ? "" :           
      decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
   }

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      // Retrieve the object from url
           var retrievedVal = getParameterByName('SecondpageValue');
           $("2ndpagelabelId").text(retrievedVal);
      });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Html page DOES NOT save your status, and we needs a server-side program to handle usually.

In your case, maybe a modal dialog is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.get()` , substitute `.replaceWith()` for `window.location` at same document

```
function updateLabels(html){
         $(html).find("#entryNumber").text("123");
         $(html).find("#responsedate").text("23-9-2015");
         $("body").replaceWith(html);
}

$.get("second.html", updateLabels);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but still dynamic label are not displaying

Comment: _"tried but still dynamic label are not displaying"_ Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ? `body` element not being replaced by `html` ?